# In Excel Sheet how to Eliminate or Remove, Filter and copy the selected records defined in another sheet using dynamic array list (VBA Module)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, autofilter

I need the experts help as I am new in this area. I am trying to create the Dynamic array Macro for Excel sheet (VBA). In which I want to eliminate (delete or hide) the number of records on the bases of data selected in one particular column (“AlertCount”) in main Sheet “**StatusReport**” using dynamic array list.
Example  :  StatusReport  (Worksheet)

[image]

**Filter_Criteria** (Worksheet)

[image]

**Expected output :**

**All record should display without "1055" and "1056" related Alert Count (Eliminate Record)**

But its removed all the records now instead of selected value

[image]

My Module as below it display the filter records only but I need to eliminate the selected filter records . VBA Module as below :

```
   Sub DeleteFilter_Data()
Set Data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StatusReport")
Set Filter_Criteria = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter_Criteria")
  
Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

Dim AlertCount_List() As String
Dim n As Integer

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Filter_Criteria.Range("A:A")) - 1
ReDim AlertCount_List(n) As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To n
        AlertCount_List(i) = Filter_Criteria.Range("A" & i + 2)
Next i

Dim Arr01 As Variant
Dim i01 As Integer
Dim i02 As Integer

'Creates a list of everything in Column I, minus everything in Filter_Criteria list
Arr01 = Range("I2", Range("I2").End(xlDown))
For i01 = 1 To UBound(Arr01, 2)
    For i02 = 0 To n - 1
    If Arr01(i01, 1) = AlertCount_List(i02) Then
        Arr01(i01, 1) = ""
    End If
    Next i02
Next i01

'Turns list into strings (needed for the Filter command).
Dim ListEdited() As String
ReDim ListEdited(1 To UBound(Arr01, 1)) As String
For i01 = 1 To UBound(Arr01, 2)
    ListEdited(i01) = Arr01(i01, 1)
Next i01

'Filter command that keeps all entries except any found within the Filter_Criteria Sheet.

 Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 9, ListEdited(), xlFilterValues
 
End Sub
```

Please help me out with corrected Macro using dynamic array list.

Thanks

Susheel

Comment: You need to know that a filter cannot be done for more than two "not equal to" conditions.

Comment: I have not much experience in it. Please let me know the  correct code for eliminate the selected value ?

Comment: I do not see any selection... Do you mean to eliminate **the two conditions (1055, 1056)**. As I tried telling to you, it is not possible to filter more than two "not equal to" type conditins. Shell I post a piece of code doing that?

Comment: I posted a piece of code able to do what you need. Didn't you find some time to test it? If tested, didn't it do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking to keep all Alert_Counts except for the ones on the Filter_Criteria sheet? The code below does this. Please let me know if I have misunderstood your questions and I will try again.

EDIT 20210630: I have updated the below code.

```
Sub HideFilter_Data()
Set Data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StatusReport")
Set Filter_Criteria = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter_Criteria")
  
Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

Dim AlertCount_List() As String
Dim n As Integer

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Filter_Criteria.Range("I:I")) - 1
ReDim AlertCount_List(n) As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To n
        AlertCount_List(i) = Filter_Criteria.Range("I" & i + 2)
Next i

Dim Arr01 As Variant
Dim i01 As Integer
Dim i02 As Integer

'Creates a list of everything in Column I, minus everything in Filter_Criteria list
Arr01 = Range("I2", Range("I2").End(xlDown))
For i01 = 1 To UBound(Arr01, 1)
    For i02 = 0 To n - 1
    If Arr01(i01, 1) = AlertCount_List(i02) Then
        Arr01(i01, 1) = ""
    End If
    Next i02
Next i01

'Turns list into strings (needed for the Filter command).
Dim ListEdited() As String
ReDim ListEdited(1 To UBound(Arr01, 1)) As String
For i01 = 1 To UBound(Arr01, 1)
    ListEdited(i01) = Arr01(i01, 1)
Next i01

'Filter command that keeps all entries except any found within the Filter_Criteria Sheet.
Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 9, ListEdited(), xlFilterValues

'Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 9, AlertCount_List(), xlFilterValues
'Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 9, Criteria1:="<> 1056"   ‘ This work fine but it's a  hard coded value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks James for reply and your understanding is correct. I was getting overflow error at  Range("I2", Range("I2").End(xlDown)). SO I have change I2 to A2.

The updated code as below because of out of range :
 
For i = 0 To n
        AlertCount_List(i) = Filter_Criteria.Range("A" & i + 1)
Next i

Now I am getting the  records on the bases of Selected Criteria  from List.

I don't know where is I am doing the mistake. Please can you test at your end.

Can you please test the code at your end with any sample list 2 or 3 column. I am totally new in this area. Thanks & reagrds

Comment: I am not too sure what your problem is and what you are asking for.
`For  i = 0 To n
AlertCount_List(i) = Filter_Criteria.Range("A" & i + 2)" should be used.`
Column I should be your AlertCount on your StatusReport Tab. And the Column A should be your AlertCount on your Filter_Criteria Tab. Could you update your question with more clarity on what exactly you need it to do, please.

Comment: Hi James I have replaced my original source code in main question request with your code that I have modified and executing as per your sample code. Now after executing the DeleteFilter_Data() function. The whole worksheet data has been deleted (removed) Screen shot added in output. I would like to keep all the records  except Alert_Counts for the ones on the Filter_Criteria.

Comment: Hi Skt, Do you mean "Hide" or do you want "Delete" I have updated the code in my answer, it should "Hide" the data, let me know if you want  to "Delete" the data instead?

Comment: Hi James,Thanks for your valuable help. I have modified your code and make to work as per my requirement. Once again thanks a lot.

Comment: Skt; Please remember to upvote and "Accept solution".

Comment: Hi How to Accept Solution ? where is the option to accept ?

Comment: open this link to see how to accept and upvote: https://imgur.com/a/AFv8Tas

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. As I said (twice) in my comments it is not possible to filter more than two "not equal to" type conditions. So, it solves the problem as you presented in your question (two conditions):

```
Sub filterCriteriaArray()
  Dim Data_sh As Worksheet, Filter_Criteria As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrC()
  
  Set Data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StatusReport")
  Set Filter_Criteria = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter_Criteria")
  lastR = Filter_Criteria.Range("A" & Filter_Criteria.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arrC = Filter_Criteria.Range("A2:A" & lastR).value
 
  Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:="<>" & arrC(1, 1), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>" & arrC(2, 1)
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

The  next code version uses `AdvancedFilter`, which allows using more criteria of the type you need, but it does not uses array as criteria. I used a trick, creating a range in a newly add sheet (hidden), based on the array extracted from your criteria sheet:

```
Sub filterCriteriaFromArray()
   Dim Data_sh As Worksheet, Filter_Criteria As Worksheet, crit As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrCr()
   Dim strHeader As String, filtRng As Range, rngCrit As Range, i As Long
   
   strHeader = "Head8" ' "AlertCount"    'important the be the correct header (of I:I column)
   Set Data_sh = ActiveSheet 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StatusReport")

   Set filtRng = Data_sh.Range(Data_sh.Range("A1"), _
         Data_sh.cells(Data_sh.UsedRange.rows.count, Data_sh.cells(1, Data_sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
   Set Filter_Criteria = Data_sh.Next 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter_Criteria")
   
   lastR = Filter_Criteria.Range("A" & Filter_Criteria.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in Filter_Criteria
   arrCr = Filter_Criteria.Range("A2:A" & lastR).value                                  'put criteria values in the array
   On Error Resume Next
    Set crit = Sheets("CriteriaSh") 'check if sheets "CriteriaSh" exists
   If err.Number <> 0 Then
        err.Clear                   'if it does not exist, it is created
        Set crit = Data_sh.Parent.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Sheets.count))
        crit.Name = "CriteriaSh"
        crit.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Else
        crit.cells.ClearContents    'if it exists its cells are cleared
    End If
   On Error GoTo 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrCr) 'Build the range to be used in AdvancedFilter criteria
        crit.cells(1, i).value = strHeader
        crit.cells(2, i).value = "<>" & arrCr(i, 1)
    Next i
    'set the criteria range:
    Set rngCrit = crit.Range(crit.Range("A1"), crit.cells(2, UBound(arrCr)))
    filtRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=rngCrit, Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Fane, Thanks for the reply. I have tested your code and its running fine for 2 value  but have its not taking more then 2 value like 1054, 1055, 1056 and 1059. How can it select the dynamic array. My motive is that we will add the numbers  in "Filter_Critearia" sheet under "AlertCount" column. that we want to eliminate from the main worksheet (StatusReport).  Its a hard coded for 2 number of values :
Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:="<>" & arrC(1, 1), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>" & arrC(2, 1)

How to  select the number dynamically.

Comment: @skt I told you **more times** that Excel `AutoFilter` does not allow filtering for condition "Not equal to" for more than two cases. This task can be done only with `AdvancedFilter` or placing the range in an array and iterating/hide rows based on conditions from the list. Now to select the dinamic array, you ca see in the above code.

Comment: @skt I will edit my answer and add a version using AdvancedFilter...

Comment: @skt Added another piece of code. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution of how to Filter, Eleminate or Hide and Copy the Selected records to another worksheet. The list of Filter data defined in another worksheet and execute the Module by Button press events on the worksheet.

For Eliminate Data case we need to create the 2 list from main worksheet and another one for eliminate the records worksheet. And Compare the both the list and replace the matched case with null or blank in main sheet

```
Sub HideFilter_Data()
Set Data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StatusReport")
Set Filter_Criteria = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter_Criteria")
  
Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

Dim AlertCount_List() As String
Dim n As Integer

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Filter_Criteria.Range("A:A")) - 1
ReDim AlertCount_List(n) As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To n
        AlertCount_List(i) = Filter_Criteria.Range("A" & i + 2)
Next i

' Create the List of main worksheet
Dim Arr01 As Variant
Dim i01 As Integer
Dim i02 As Integer

Dim r As Integer
Dim r1 As Integer
r = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Data_sh.Range("I:I")) - 2
ReDim StatusCount_List(r + 1) As String

For r1 = 0 To r
        StatusCount_List(r1) = Data_sh.Range("I" & r1 + 2)
Next r1


'Creates a list of everything in Column I, minus everything in Filter_Criteria list
Dim str As Variant
Dim cnt As Integer
cnt = 0

' Executing the double loop for comparing both the List and eleminate the match data from the main sheet.
For Each Item In StatusCount_List
 For Each subItem In AlertCount_List
     If Item = subItem Then
          StatusCount_List(cnt) = ""
         End If
 Next subItem
 cnt = cnt + 1
Next Item

 Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 9, StatusCount_List(), xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

**Main Worksheet :**

[image]

**Eliminating Criteria (Hide the records)**

[image]

**Output (Eliminated / Hide/ Remove) as below:**

[image]

**Filter the selected records. Filter list defined in another worksheet.**

If we need to select the selected record from the list of another sheet by using dynamic array.

```
Option Explicit ' Force explicit variable declaration.

Sub Filter_Data()
Dim Data_sh As Worksheet
Dim Filter_Criteria As Worksheet
Dim Output_Sh As Worksheet


Set Data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StatusReport")
Set Filter_Criteria = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter_Criteria")
Set Output_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

Output_Sh.UsedRange.Clear
Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

Dim AlertCount_List() As String
Dim n As Integer

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Filter_Criteria.Range("A:A")) - 1
ReDim AlertCount_List(n) As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To n
        AlertCount_List(i) = Filter_Criteria.Range("A" & i + 2)
Next i

  Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 9, AlertCount_List(), xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Output :

[image]

**Copy the selected records to new worksheet. Filter list defined in another worksheet.**

Option Explicit ' Force explicit variable declaration.

```
Sub CopyFilter_Data()
Dim Data_sh As Worksheet
Dim Filter_Criteria As Worksheet
Dim Output_Sh As Worksheet


Set Data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StatusReport")
Set Filter_Criteria = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter_Criteria")
Set Output_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

Output_Sh.UsedRange.Clear
Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

Dim AlertCount_List() As String
Dim n As Integer

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Filter_Criteria.Range("A:A")) - 1
ReDim AlertCount_List(n) As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To n
        AlertCount_List(i) = Filter_Criteria.Range("A" & i + 2)
Next i
    

'Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 9, Array("1055", "1056"), xlFilterValues
Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 9, AlertCount_List(), xlFilterValues

Data_sh.UsedRange.Copy Output_Sh.Range("A1")
Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

'MsgBox ("Data has been copied")

End Sub
```

Output :

[image]